# Change font size with a button

Tags: javascript, button, fonts, size

I was trying to change the font size of the posts on my blog with a button...
Something like this:

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="document.body.style.fontSize='x-large';">BIG</a></p>
```

The problem is, every other text but the post text change in size.

I think the problem is that the text in the posts is between the following tags:

```
 <span style="font-size: large;">Blah blah blah</span>
```

So, it is possible to use a button to change te size of this text to "large", "x-large" and "xx-large"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i managed to found a solution thanks to a friend who knows some programming.
I used the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function
SuperGrande() {var ss = document.querySelectorAll(".entry-content span, 
.entry-content div");
for (var n=0;n<ss.length;n++) ss[n].style.fontSize="xx-large";}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">function
Grande() {var ss = document.querySelectorAll(".entry-content span, .entry- 
content div");
for (var n=0;n<ss.length;n++) ss[n].style.fontSize="x-large";}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">function
Normal() {var ss = document.querySelectorAll(".entry-content span, .entry- 
content div");
for (var n=0;n<ss.length;n++) ss[n].style.fontSize="large";}
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Normal()" id="plustext">Normal</a> | 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Grande()" id="minustext">Grande</a> | 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="SuperGrande()" id="minustext">Muy 
Grande</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

so the way specificity works in CSS takes into account inline styling as the strongest factor (other than the `!important` which should be avoided whenever possible).

In your case the inline style takes precedence because it has the highest specificity so there's not much you can do in order to overwrite that style. My suggestion would be to start exploring the use of classes in CSS and maybe assign a different class to the blog post upon click.

Something as simple as:

```
.largeText {
  font-size: large;
}

.xLargeText {
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

might work. I'll let you figure out how to exploit classes to get the result you want. So to answer your question, YES! It's possible but you need to better understand CSS specificity rules to know how your changes can actually affect the styling of your page. I hope this was helpful!